# Component Re-Render generating issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am new in `React` & `React Native`. I used the classless component for my `React Native` app. For example, I have home screen and home screen have 10 upcoming events. so I displayed all the events using `Flatlist` with `react-redux` and `redux`. Now the thing is all the events joining are `real time` using `sokcte.io`. and i also set CountDown. When some one join any event i emit that socket and update real time joining. No the issue is that, when i update specific event data using `redux` react native re-render home screen component so CountDown also re-render and its looks like stuck CountDown and then start it again.

Please can you help?

Here is My Screen

```
const EventScreen = (props) => {

    console.log('Event Screen Rendered')

    const [isLoading,setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    const navigation = props.navigation;
    const dispatchEvents = useDispatch();

    const SOCKET_URL = 'http://192.168.43.142:8080/';


    const Events = useSelector(state => state.EventReducer.Events);

    const _connectSocket = useCallback(() => {

        var socket = io.connect(SOCKET_URL, { forceNode: true });

        socket.on('EventProcess',(d) => {
            dispatchEvents(EventAction.onEventOver(d));
            dispatchEvents(EventAction.onEventOverChangeActiveEvent(d));
        });


        // New  Joining
        socket.on('EventJoined',(Event) => {
            dispatchEvents(EventAction.onEventJoined(Event))
        })

    },[]);


    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        dispatchEvents(EventAction.fetchEvents())
        .then( () => {
            setIsLoading(false);
        })
        .catch( () => {
            setIsLoading(false);
        })
        _connectSocket();
    }, []);

    return <View>

        <FlatList
            data={Events}
            renderItem={(event) => <EventCard event={event.item} navigation={navigation} />}
            keyExtractor={event => event._id}
        />

    </View>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add extraData prop to your FlatList component like:

```
 extraData={Events}
```